# Rewrite subdirectory to appear as another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder containing an app in https://www.example.com/some/subdirectory/folder/. I'd like for visitors to be able to access this at simply https://www.example.com/app/. Essentially running all of the files from the /some/subdirectory/folder/ as if they were in /app/ (a virtual folder).

I've tried several variations of mod_rewrite and just can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you need to access the content of the folder

```
/subdir/subsubdir
```

under the virtual folder

```
/app
```

This can be done by the following .htaccess file placed in the webroot of your application:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten}" "!=1" 
RewriteRule ^/?subdir/subsubdir/(.*)$ /app/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/?app/(.*)$ /subdir/subsubdir/$1 [QSA,L,E=rewritten:1]
```

Here you can find more information on url-/folder-mapping and also a quick overview concerning mod_rewrite:

https://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/#url-mapping